# Validating string contains 'aaa' but not contains 'bbb'

Tags: regex, validation

Fast RegExp question.

I must check whether a given string contains `aaa` but not contains `bbb`. I can use only regexp (http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Examples:

- `aaa` - ok
- `bbb` - fail
- `aaabb` - ok
- `aaabbb` - fail
- `aaaTEXT` - ok
- `aaaTEXTbbb` - fail
- `aaTEXTa` - fail

Comment: Is something like `bbbTEXTaaa` possible?

Comment: @Raisch no [some more chars to post].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex `(?=.*a{3})(?!.*b{3}).+`

`(?=.*a{3})` contain aaa

`(?!.*b{3}).+` dont contain bbb

`.+` select all string which satisfies the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit faster?

```
var string = "aaabbb";

if ( string.indexOf("aaa") !== -1 && string.indexOf("bbb") === -1 ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I can use ONLY regular expressions, please read more carefully.